# how to project a flat image to spherical mercator EPGS:900013 to use in a Image Layer in openlayers

Tags: image, openlayers, gdal, map-projections

I have a flat 400x400 pixels image which represents an area of 400x400 kilometers. I need to draw this image as an overlay on my OpenLayers mapping system. I use OpenStreetMap/Google Maps as base layers. I want to draw the overlay image using an Image Layer and I want to center my overlay image at a specific lat/lon point. The projection of the base layer is EPSG:900913 which is, in fact, the projection used by OpenStreetMap and Google Maps.

What I have understood (please correct me if I'm wrong), is that I can't use a flat, 'unprojected' image as an Image Layer, but I have to do a sort of 'reprojecting' to adjust the image to be compliant with the projection of the map, which is EPSG:900913. Searching here and the net, it seems I should use a library/tool called GDAL to do this, but whereas I am completely new to this I ask you:

- Can anyone address me on how to use it?
- Could you possibly tell me if what I have just said is correct and the way I described here is valid?
- How could I use gdal to translate my flat unprojected 400x400 pixels image to an image projected in EPSG:900913, and suitable to be put as an Image Layer as an overlay?

Thanks.

I added the image as requested.

[image]

The answer provided by @capdragon was useful and let me going one step further. Anyway I have still some problems. I did this:

1. used gdal_translate to set GCPs to the four corners and the center of the image like this:

`gdal_translate -of "GTIFF" -gcp 0 0 8.6923 45.5427 -gcp 400 0 13.8149 45.5427 -gcp 200 200 11.2536 43.771702 -gcp 0 400 8.8413 41.9460 -gcp 400 400 13.6659 41.9460 quadrprod.png quadrprod_gpc.tif`

This way I get a quadrprod_gcp.tif output. Then.

1. used gdalwarp to apply the GCPs set in the point above and set the right projection, which is EPSG:4326 like this:

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 quadrprod_gcp.tif quadrprod_gcp_warped.tif`

This way I get a final quadrprod_gcp_warped.tif. The resulting image is no more 400x400 pixels but is 458x331 pixels. Then if I use gdalinfo to look at it, I found this:

```
gdalinfo quadrprod_gcp_warped.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: quadrprod_gcp_warped.tif
Size is 458, 331
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (8.768046497499189,45.547291862003739)
Pixel Size = (0.010877474938832,-0.010877474938832)
Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   8.7680465,  45.5472919) (  8d46'4.97"E, 45d32'50.25"N)
Lower Left  (   8.7680465,  41.9468477) (  8d46'4.97"E, 41d56'48.65"N)
Upper Right (  13.7499300,  45.5472919) ( 13d44'59.75"E, 45d32'50.25"N)
Lower Right (  13.7499300,  41.9468477) ( 13d44'59.75"E, 41d56'48.65"N)
Center      (  11.2589883,  43.7470698) ( 11d15'32.36"E, 43d44'49.45"N)
Band 1 Block=458x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=458x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=458x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=458x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

As you can see the 4 corners and the center lat/lon are different from the values I set using -gcp values. My questions:

- Why the lat/lon values returned by gdalinfo are different from the values I set in step 1 using -gpc?
- Is it normal or am I doing something wrong?
- What is next step? Should I translate the image again from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:900913?
- When I place my image as overlay in openlayers, when I create the bounds object, should I use as southwest and northeast corners, the values I used in the -gcp or the final values I see with gdalinfo?

Comment: You should at least know the projection of the image in order to reproject it. If its the same as your target, you dont have to use GDAL and can calculate the corner coordinates directly to use with `OpenLayers.Layer.Image`.

Comment: do you see any control points if you run `gdalinfo <image>`?

Comment: Can you make the image available here to download?

Comment: @capdragon: I edited my answer adding the image.

Comment: @Magallo all I see is an image with 4 colored squares on it. Not sure if that's a default SE image that displays when it cannot display an uploaded image.

Comment: @Magallo I would upload it to dropbox or a webserver where it can be downloaded. I imagine it's pretty big.

Comment: No no, the imagine is exactly a squadre with four subsquares. Top left square is blue, top right is green, bottom left is yellow and bottom right is red. This is just a test imagine. I decided to use this because it's very easy to determine if the center of the image is positioned in the right expected lat/lon or not. My real images are in fact very different from this, but for testing purposes it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is correct.

You basically want to set some control points (reference points) using `gdal_translate` then warp the image using `gdalwarp`.

So for a rough projection you could simply use the corner cordinates to set 4 control points like so. (These examples are using EPSG:4326, but you can use EPSG:900913.

## Set 4 control points (corner coordinates)

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 -89.38939600 30.39282800 -gcp 1024 0 -87.00029400 30.01043900 -gcp 0 1250 -89.99424800 27.37030800 -gcp 1024 1250 -87.67748400 26.98606100 "originalImage.tif" "image_trans.tiff"
```

The above is saying that pixel x=0 and y=0 is equal to "-89.38939600 30.39282800" pixel x=1024 and y=0 is -87.00029400 30.01043900 and so forth.

## Warp the image:

```
gdalwarp -dstalpha -t_srs EPSG:4326 image_trans.tiff image_warped.tiff
```

If the warping isn't good enough you're going to need to set more control points on the image.

## UPDATE

I downloaded your image and ran the commands you have. Everything worked fine for me:
|

```
    captDragon@liberatecuba:/media/Data/tmp/orthoTesting$ gdal_translate -of "GTIFF" -gcp 0 0 8.6923 45.5427 -gcp 400 0 13.8149 45.5427 -gcp 200 200 11.2536 43.771702 -gcp 0 400 8.8413 41.9460 -gcp 400 400 13.6659 41.9460 quadrprod.png quadrprod_gpc.tif
    Input file size is 400, 400
    0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
captDragon@liberatecuba:/media/Data/tmp/orthoTesting$ gdalinfo quadrprod_gpc.tif 
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files: quadrprod_gpc.tif
    Size is 400, 400
    Coordinate System is `'
    GCP Projection = 
    GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
              (0,0) -> (8.6923,45.5427,0)
    GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
              (400,0) -> (13.8149,45.5427,0)
    GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
              (200,200) -> (11.2536,43.771702,0)
    GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
              (0,400) -> (8.8413,41.946,0)
    GCP[  4]: Id=5, Info=
              (400,400) -> (13.6659,41.946,0)
    Image Structure Metadata:
      INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
    Lower Left  (    0.0,  400.0)
    Upper Right (  400.0,    0.0)
    Lower Right (  400.0,  400.0)
    Center      (  200.0,  200.0)
    Band 1 Block=400x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
    Band 2 Block=400x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
    Band 3 Block=400x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
    Band 4 Block=400x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer is good and let me going one step further. Anyway I have still some problems. Please look back at my question. I modified it adding more info.

Comment: I've gotten values like this `8d46'4.97"E` when the input values are not expected to be within the projection grid bounds. I noticed you missed the `-a_srs EPSG:4326` portion in the `gdal_transalate` command. This should fix the problem as it will specify what projection the image is using.