# How to overlay GRADS image into OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, map-projections, grads

I need to overlay a GRADS image into an OpenLayers map, but they do not fit each another because some lands are not in the position even the lower-left and upper-right of the image are in the right place.

I guess it is due to the projection difference between the image and the map as I set "mproj scaled" for the image and "EPSG:3857" for the map. But I cannot find any common projection for both of them.

Does anyone know how to put them together?

**UPDATE**

I finally find the soluation in [Magallo's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960229/how-to-project-a-flat-image-to-spherical-mercator-epgs900013-to-use-in-a-image?rq=1) to re-project  the GRADS image to "EPSG:3857" with gdal.

Answer (score 0):

I used to stuck in the same problem like you and I decided to find other solution to draw image instead of GrADS.

The reason is: the map projection of OpenLayers (or GoogleMap) is Mercator but as far as I know GrADS doesn't have this projection currently.

I strongly recommend that you try with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), matplotlib provide various map projections including [Mercator](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/merc.html).

Try with some [examples](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html), it'll take much time to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I finally find another way to re-project the image.

Comment: do you continue using GrADS? which projection do you choose?